# Make draggable Live Helper Chat widget iframe when draggable image is disallow

Tags: draggable

I have a [WordPress website](https://blog.peopleinside.it) where I activated a protection for disallow image drag and drop because this allow visitor to drag and save on the Desktop images...

As soon I activate the option to disallow image drag is disabled also the possibility to drag the live helper chat widget that I have on footer right bottom of the screen.

I want exclude this element from the protection so user can move (drag) the widget of the chat. Any help or suggestion, please?

I know usually in the web is not liked protection like disable right click etc... but let me decide this on my website, I AM looking now for a solution to allow this x-frame option to be draggable again also with the active protection.
Thanks, any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK I do not find how to solve this issue but I found that disable block to prevent image drag and put this code:

```
/* Example 1: Makes all the img non-reactive to any mouse events such as dragging, hovering, clicking etc */
img {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Solve my issue by making the image not draggable.